# Create new node based on id from another xml, loop

Tags: xslt

I would like to add a  node based on , but the problem is the categories are in a separate file and moreover I would like to loop to find all  based on .

Let me show an example:

category.xml:

```
<ROOT>
<GROUPITEM>
<G_ID>1368</G_ID>
<GROUP>Phone</GROUP>
<PARENT>0</PARENT>
</GROUPITEM>

<GROUPITEM>
<G_ID>1194</G_ID>
<GROUP>Apple</GROUP>
<PARENT>1368</PARENT>
</GROUPITEM>

<GROUPITEM>
<G_ID>1195</G_ID>
<GROUP>2019</GROUP>
<PARENT>1194</PARENT>
</GROUPITEM>
</ROOT>
```

item.xml:

```
<ROOT>
<SHOPITEM>
    <PRODUCT_ID>96555</PRODUCT_ID>
    <GROUP_ID>1195</GROUP_ID>
    <PRODUCT_NAME>Apple iPhone 8 Plus</PRODUCT_NAME>
</SHOPITEM>
</ROOT>
```

Example output:

```
<ROOT>
<SHOPITEM>
    <PRODUCT_ID>96555</PRODUCT_ID>
    <GROUP_ID>1195</GROUP_ID>
    <PRODUCT_NAME>Apple iPhone 8 Plus</PRODUCT_NAME>
    <CATEGORY>Phone | Apple | 2019</CATEGORY>
</SHOPITEM>
</ROOT>
```

In simple words I am looking for a way to create  node (in item.xml) and add here value ( from category.xml) based on  (item.xml): search in category.xml for the same  -> if found, add it -> search more based on  (if success add separator + value) -> loop.

Comment: Does your processor support XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Yes, XSLT 2.0 or 3.0, doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like (untested):

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="group" match="GROUPITEM" use="G_ID" />

<xsl:template match="SHOPITEM">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        <CATEGORY>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('group', GROUP_ID, document('category.xml'))"/>
        </CATEGORY>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="GROUPITEM">
    <xsl:variable name="parent" select="key('group', PARENT)" />
    <xsl:if test="$parent">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$parent"/>
        <xsl:text> | </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="GROUP"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You are a genius, it seems so easy after reading someone else code.

Comment: How would you modify the code to leave `<ROOT>` node in the output? I tried `<xsl:template match="@* | node()"> <xsl:copy> <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/> </xsl:copy> </xsl:template>`, but it is duplicating the `<CATEGORY>`

Comment: I believe adding the identity transform template as you show should work. `<CATEGORY>` cannot be duplicated if it doesn't exist in the source XML.